# Massive inserts kill arangod (well, almost)

Tags: arangodb

I was wondering of anyone has ever encountered this:

When inserting documents via AQL, I can easily kill my arango server. For example

```
FOR i IN 1 .. 10
  FOR u IN users
    INSERT {
        _from: u._id,
        _to: CONCAT("posts/",CEIL(RAND()*2000)),
        displayDate: CEIL(RAND()*100000000)
    } INTO canSee
```

(where users contains 500000 entries), the following happens

- canSee becomes completely locked (also no more reads)
- memory consumption goes up
- arangosh or web console becomes unresponsive
- fails [ArangoError 2001: Could not connect]
- server is still running, accessing collection gives timeouts
- it takes around 5-10 minutes until the server recovers and I can access the collection again
- access to any other collection works fine

So ok, I'm creating a lot of entries and AQL might be implemented in a way that it does this in bulk. When doing the writes via db.save method it works but is much slower.

Also I suspect this might have to do with write-ahead cache filling up.

But still, is there a way I can fix this? Writing a lot of entries to a database should not necessarily kill it.

Logs say

```
DEBUG [./lib/GeneralServer/GeneralServerDispatcher.h:411] shutdownHandler called, but no handler is known for task

DEBUG [arangod/VocBase/datafile.cpp:949] created datafile '/usr/local/var/lib/arangodb/journals/logfile-6623368699310.db' of size 33554432 and page-size 4096

DEBUG [arangod/Wal/CollectorThread.cpp:1305] closing full journal '/usr/local/var/lib/arangodb/databases/database-120933/collection-4262707447412/journal-6558669721243.db'
```

bests

Comment: Try the same without the calls to `RAND()`, i.e. for example `_to: CONCAT("posts/", 0)` and `displayDate: 0`.

Comment: But then the first loop would be pointless, because I'd rewrite the already existing documents?

Comment: Whatever, then instead of `0` put `i`. The point is try it without `RAND()`.

Comment: On what kind of machine does the query run? Are there still idle cores available or is it a single-core machine? Do the documents and indexes completely fit into the server's RAM or will it start swapping at some point during the query because all physical memory is allocated?

Comment: I changed the query so it reads `FOR i IN 1 .. 50
 FOR u IN users
  INSERT {
   _from: u._id,
   _to: CONCAT("posts/",i),
   displayDate: 100000000
  } INTO canSee` ... still the server bonks out. Machine is MacBook Pro, 8 Gigs of RAM. And yes, when I run this query, it starts swapping heavily, so I guess the AQL tries to insert the data in one transaction?

Comment: Some short update on this one ... the query just finished (no more journals were written), but arangodb was zombied after it. Virtual Memory was at 30GB and stayed there. Also the sync job that writes journal to the database never happened. The only endpoint that was accessible was _api/version :). I'm now restarting the db and he is proceeding the logs which should take a while...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The above query will insert 5M documents into ArangoDB in a single transaction. This will take a while to complete, and while the transaction is still ongoing, it will hold lots of (potentially needed) rollback data in memory.

Additionally, the above query will first build up all the documents to insert in memory, and once that's done, will start inserting them. Building all the documents will also consume a lot of memory. When executing this query, you will see the memory usage steadily increasing until at some point the disk writes will kick in when the actual inserts start.

There are at least two ways for improving this:

- it might be beneficial to split the query into multiple, smaller transactions. Each transaction then won't be as big as the original one, and will not block that many system resources while ongoing.
- for the query above, it technically isn't necessary to build up all documents to insert in memory first, and only after that insert them all.  Instead, documents read from `users` could be inserted into `canSee` as they arrive. This won't speed up the query, but it will significantly lower memory consumption during query execution for result sets as big as above. It will also lead to the writes starting immediately, and thus write-ahead log collection starting earlier. Not all queries are eligible for this optimization, but some (including the above) are. I worked on a mechanism today that detects eligible queries and executes them this way. The change was pushed into the devel branch today, and will be available with ArangoDB 2.5.

Comment: I also often have this kind of queries. in most of my cases, I don't need transaction security, but want to move forward within one single AQL statement. (Typicall cases are e.g. when precalculting things into a volatile collection). Is there a way to formulate AQL statements in a "no-transaction-mode"?